# Data validation using openpyxl isnt writing to file - code enclosed

Tags: python, validation, openpyxl

The code to actually write each file runs great. The problem I'm having is that the data validation piece doesn't appear to be doing anything. No drop downs are being created in the range I'm referencing.

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

```
%%time

import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as ew
import csv as csv
import os
import glob
import openpyxl

#remove existing files from directory
files = glob.glob(#filename)
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)

pendpath = #filename
df = pd.read_sas(pendpath)

allusers = df.UserID_NB.unique()
listuserpath = #filename
listusers = pd.read_csv(listuserpath)

listusers = listusers['USER_ID'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip())

for id in listusers:
    x = df.loc[df['UserID_NB']==id]
    path = #filename
    x.to_excel(path, sheet_name = str(id), index = False)

    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = path)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(str(id))
    maxrow = sheet.max_row    

    from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

    dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Yes,No"', allow_blank=False, showDropDown = True)
    rangevar = 'R1:T'+ str(maxrow)
    dv.ranges.append(rangevar)
    wb.save(path)
    print str(id), rangevar
```

Code for Basic Sheet

```
 import openpyxl 

 wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
 ws = wb.active
 sheet.title = 'testsheet'

path = '#filepath'
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Yes,No"', allow_blank=False, showDropDown = True)
dv.ranges.append('A1')
wb.save(path)
```

Comment: can I ask why you are importing inside a loop?

Comment: Looks like you may be repeatedly overwriting the same file. I suggest you try the relevant code with a simple Excel file.

Comment: Dmitry - I'm creating individual excel files for each user id within a csv file (normally I'd have it iterate through all unique user id's but this request was for a subset of users). Looping through the list seemed to be the most efficient way to do that

Comment: Charlie - I added 'Code for Basic Sheet' attempting your suggestion. Same result - the workbook and sheet were created however no validation was present within the sheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are missing to add the `dv` to the `worksheet`**.

```
>>> # Add the data-validation object to the worksheet
>>> ws.add_data_validation(dv)
```

[Read the docs about validation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html)

Comment: Nice, that worked. For some reason it's not showing drop downs but the validation piece is working. Thanks